# Can't upload an image to Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

When i choose an image from gallery and set it to ImageView it is working . but when i click on the button to uploading this image progressdialog doesn't dismiss and image will not be uploaded to storage.

Manifiest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

dependencies Build.gradle(Module:app)

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
impleme;ntation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

dependencies Build.gradle(project)

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

}
```

image of Firebase storage rules

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHS0X.png)

Add_post.java

public class Add_Post extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText edt_title,edt_descripion;
private ImageView img;
private final int GALLERY_INTENT = 1;
private StorageReference reference;
private Uri uri;
private ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__post);

    reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    edt_descripion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_despost);
    edt_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_titlepost);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_post);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addposts_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_submit){

        progress_submit();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri  = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void progress_submit() {
    String title = edt_title.getText().toString();
    String description = edt_descripion.getText().toString();

    pd.setMessage("Uploading...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(title)  && TextUtils.isEmpty(description) && uri!=null) {
        StorageReference filepath = reference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(Add_Post.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: add OnFailureListener and try to log the error.

Comment: there isn't error when i get log in addOnFailureListener.  progressdialog continues . image doesn't send to storage until progressdialog to be dismiss.

Comment: Chech the value of uri before sending it to storage. Is that null ??

Comment: No. it isn't null . uri take data correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a logical bug, as you are checking when title & description is empty only then upload the image. So change your code as done below-

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)  && !TextUtils.isEmpty(description) && uri!=null) {
    StorageReference filepath = reference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(Add_Post.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload the image to Firebase storage, add an android service into your manifest.xml
Below was a sample android service added:-

```
<service
       android:name=".service.ImageUploadService"
       android:exported="false" />
```

The demo and source code were provided by Firebase here:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage